# JPA createNativeQuery not mapping to Entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, entitymanager, jpa

I am trying to use createNativeQuery to get a result set from my database and map it to a list of Entity objects.

When i do

```
List<MyObject> results = this.em.createNativeQuery(query, MyClass.class).getResultList();
```

I end up with an array of Entity objects that is the correct size, and mapped to the columns correctly, but they are all the same object. The first result returned gets duplicated for every entry in my list.

[image]

In the picture above you can see that I get data back, and if i inspect the ovbjects they are mapped to my columns properly. But they are all the same object.

But if i do

```
List<Object[]> objects = this.em.createNativeQuery(query, Object.class).getResultList();
```

I get a list of distinct Objects like it should be. But they are not mapped to my Entity class.

[image]

In the above pic, you can see that when I use `Object` and stead of my Entity class type, I get a result set of distinct objects for each row returned. I cannot figure out why when i use my Entity class it just repeats the same row over and over.

Does anyone know what could be causing me to get a list of the same object each time?

My query is selecting from a Pipelined function in a stored procedure

```
String query = "select * from table(myschema.mypackage.myfunction(input_var))";
```

**UPDATE**

The pipelined function I am calling inside my procedure returns about 200 rows. For testing purposes, I have only mapped the first few of the columns.

My Entity class has column mappings for the first 13 of the 200 columns. 
My query that calls the function is doing a `select *`, so, it is returning all 200 columns and mapping the first 13. I thought this was a possible issue, but I just tried it with a new test class I made and doing a `select *` from a regular table into an Entity that only had 2 of the columns mapped. There was no issue. It returned a list of distinct objects.

My conclusion is that there must be something preventing Hibernate from iterating through the result set of my pipelined function. It returns the correct number of rows, but it gets stuck on the first row and just creates that object over and over.

The issue doesnt seem to have anything to do with my column mappings

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: @fg78nc I added an example. This is for work, and I cannot post explicit code. I am calling a pipelined function in a stored procedure. My entity class is mapped to the column names returned by the pipelined function. Everything works correctly when I do not provide my Entity class. But when I do provide it, it just get the same object repeated. And that object is the first row returned from the pipelined function.

Comment: Do column aliases in the SQL string match directly with column mapping for a single entity?

Comment: @fg78nc I am using `select *`, no aliases. And all the columns are mapped correctly otherwise I would not be getting anything returned from `.getResultsList()`.

Comment: Try to add explicit ResultSet mapping, please see my answer

Comment: Was a unique identifier included in the '13' mappings you mention?  If the ID isn't included, they will appear to be data for the same object, causing it to return only the one instance for all the rows.

Comment: @Chris I had it on a column that turned out to be not distinct and i didnt notice it when i wrote it because I saw the size of the list returned was correct. I just answered my question mentioning that was the issue. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

Turns out I was just not paying attention and over thinking what I had done.

I had my `@Id` annotation in my Entity class on a column that turned out was not distinct. When i was checking me work I was only paying attention to the size of the list being returned.

After fixing my `@Id` on the right column, it is now returning the full list of distinct objects.

Comment: Oh, that one helped! Getting bugged results for days, not knowing where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Did you trying using something like this?

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("stored_procedure_name");
q.registerStoredProcedureParameter("empList", something.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

List<MyObject> myObj= (List<>)q.getOutputParameterValue("paramValue");
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to provide explicit Result Set mapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="myMapping",
    entities={@EntityResult(entityClass=MyClass.class)}
```

And then

```
em.createNativeQuery(query, "myMapping").getResultList();
```